# Apply formula to specific numpy array values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2 dimensional array in numpy and need to apply a mathematical formula just to some values of the array which match certain criteria. This can be made using a for loop and if conditions however I think using numpy where() method works faster.

My code so far is this but it doesn't work

```
cond2 = np.where((SPN >= -alpha) & (SPN <= 0))
SPN[cond2] = -1*math.cos((SPN[cond2]*math.pi)/(2*alpha))
```

The values in the orginal array need to be replaced with the corresponding value after applying the formula.

Any ideas of how to make this work? I'm working with big arrays so need and efficient way of doing it.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
cond2 = (SPN >= -alpha) & (SPN <= 0)
SPN[cond2] = -np.cos(SPN[cond2]*np.pi/(2*alpha))
```

Comment: Might as well call `np.pi` as well so everything comes from the same library.

Comment: @Hooked yes I missed it ... :)